# Detecting source of change in JPanel size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, propertychangelistener

I have a class called TablePanel descended from JPanel.  An instance of this class is resizing itself sometimes when I click on a check box that is in another part of the frame.

Is there some sort of event listener or something so I can track down what event is actually causing this TablePanel to resize?

I have tried adding the following to the constructor of TablePanel:

```
        addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("TablePanel evt: " + evt);
            }
        });
```

but this isn't 'firing' when the resize happens.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for the componentResized event of the ComponentListener.

Although I'm not sure why you need this. The layout manager of your panel should handle this the resizing/layout of any components on the panel.

This won't give you the actual source of the change. The source event is likely the frame being resized and then the layout managers do their job.

> An instance of this class is resizing itself sometimes when I click on a check box that is in another part of the frame.

I have never seen this happen. Clicking on a checkbox should not change its size, therefore there is no reason for components on the panel to be layed out again. You must have some strange code. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.